# Regarding toHexString method in the Integer?

Tags: java

I would like to convert a byte to its hex from string, when I use method 
`Integer.toHexString`, the positive number is OK, but the negative number is outputed as
something like `ffffffa7`, I would like to always get two char string, how to do that?

Why there is no `toHexString` method in the Byte class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
String.format("%02x", value)
```